# Proof Verification: Let $a$ be a positive number in $\mathbb N$. Then there exists exactly one natural number $b$ such that $b\text{++} =a$.

Tags: number-theory, induction, solution-verification, natural-numbers

I've seen a few proofs for this lemma...but I've been playing around trying to put it in a form that makes the most intuitive sense to me. If anyone could verify the legitimacy of the proof, I would greatly appreciate it.

> Let $a$ be a positive number in $\mathbb N$. Then there exists exactly one natural number $b$ such that $b\text{++} =a$.

The notation $++$ is from Tao's Analysis I book and denotes the successor function.

I am going to implement two consecutive contradiction-styled proofs to prove this statement.

Firstly, I am going to assume that the existence part is true and verify the uniqueness of the existence.

Suppose $b$ is not unique and there exists another element $c$ such that $c++ = a$. By transitivity of equality, $b++=a=c++ \implies b++=c++$. By one of the Peano Axioms, *if $n++=m++$, then we must have $n=m$*. Therefore, $b=c$ and we see that if there exists a $b$, then this $b$ must be unique.

Secondly, I want to prove that there simply exists a $b$ for all positive $a$. Consider the following induction where "**predecessor**" is the property of interest (for definition's sake, $b$ in the statement $b++=a$ is the predecessor):

**Base Case**: $1$ has a predecessor. Certainly. $0$ is the predecessor of $1$ because $0++=1$

**$n$ assumption**: assume $n$ has a predecessor.

**prove $n++$ has a predecessor**: of course $n++$ has a predecessor. It's predecessor is $n$ because $(n)++=n++$.

Therefore, $\forall n \geq 1$, where $n \in \mathbb N$, $n$ has a predecessor. Now by one of the Peano Axioms, *$n++\neq0$ for all natural number $n$*. This is equivalent to saying $0$ has no predecessor (based on my definition of predecessor).

So, let's assume by contradiction, that positive $a$ has no predecessor. Therefore, the only available element in $\mathbb N$ for $a$ to be is $0$. However, $a$ is positive, by assumption. Therefore, this is a contradiction so every positive $a$ must have a predecessor. And by the first contradiction (above), this predecessor must be unique.

Are there any issues with this proof? Thank you.

Comment: Technical nit: a better choice would have been ${++}b$. For $b{++}$ evaluates to the old value of $b$ (and as a side effect increments the stored value).

Comment: Tao makes a comment about this in his notation (referencing the computer science expression).

Comment: It's mathematics, so there's no such thing as "stored value". Just a nitpick about the notation because it conjures up the wrong image in a programmer's mind.

Comment: About your proof: I think instead of "then we must have" it's better to plainly state "then we have". And instead of "then this $b$ must be unique" to say "thus $b$ is unique". And the name is P**e**ano, not P**i**ano. For the second part, instead of the artificial contradiction, note that $a$ being positive means $a \geqslant 1$, therefore a predecessor exists, by the induction.

Comment: Oh, hah! Thank you for the Peano corrections (changed). And for your second point, understood. I guess what I did with the 2nd contradiction is somewhat redundant because the induction implicitly forces the statement to already be true.

Comment: @Daniel  in PARI GP it's backwards b++ adds one but it can't be used with equals.